# Pivot Filtering/Calculated Field

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

Let me get strict to the point. I'm trying to filter Piv. Values in my Table - after few hours I realized, that I don't know how to do it by myself.

```
Month |People| Pass
-------------------------
05-'12| 123  | 10     
06-'12| 33   | 3      
07-'12| 555  | 4      
08-'12| 123  | 13     
09-'12| 23   | 5
```

This is an example of Piv.Table. Rows stands for Years(months) when test was done, People is an amount (Count) of tests done overall and Pass column is amount of tests which result Was above some value.

Now - I'd like to have in a column percentage amount of people whom results were above some value. First of all i tried to create **"Pass"** column from Pivot level. I was wrong. Tried many times to create some Calculated Fileds (with IF, COUNTIF (most accurate) etc.) to extract the number of people (*Count*) whom pass the test from **"People"** - I store the results of the test in my source table there, in pivot use *Count* instead of *Sum*. Unfortunately, either it's not possible or just don't know how to do it.

But let's leave the **"Pass"** , I've created some column in ma source data, that do the trick. What i want the most is percentage amount of people whom pass the test in certain month - in other words, 200 done the test, 100 pass it and, obvious, 50% is the result what I want to get OR  **"Pass/People *100%"**.

That's all. Sorry for the amount of text. I forgot to mention, i need it to create pivot chart and will use it many times. Thats why don't want to do it manually.
Thanks for any thoughts, help and ideas. Cheers.

Comment: Show an example of what your raw data looks like as well as your pivot table. Often it is simpler to perform math on raw data and then just include those results in the pivot table.

Comment: Also - please clarify what it is that you want and how you want it to look.